# Como obter o path de um arquivo(HttpPostedFileBase)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Gostaria de obter o path(caminho) de onde meu arquivo está vindo.

Model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione o arquivo a ser importado.")]
    [Display(Name = "Arquivo ")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Arquivo)
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Arquivo, new { type = "file", name="Arquivo" })
```

Agradeço todas as respostas.

Answer (score 3):

Supondo uma *Action* de *Controller*, você pode obter o arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
    private const String DiretorioCurriculos = "~/Curriculos/";

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EnviarCurriculo([Bind(Include = "CurriculoCandidatoId,NomeCandidato,Email,TelefoneContato,TelefoneCelular,ArquivoCurriculo,SetorPreterido,Comentarios")] CurriculoCandidato curriculoCandidato)
    {
        if (curriculoCandidato.Arquivo != null && curriculoCandidato.Arquivo.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string nomeArquivo = Regex.Replace(curriculoCandidato.NomeCandidato + "-" + Path.GetFileName(curriculoCandidato.Arquivo.FileName), @"\s+", "");
            string caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(DiretorioCurriculos), nomeArquivo);
            curriculoCandidato.Arquivo.SaveAs(caminho);

            curriculoCandidato.CaminhoArquivoCurriculo = nomeArquivo;
        }

        ...
```

`Arquivo` é do tipo [`HttpPostedFileBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx).

Você pode também manipular os bytes diretamente através da propriedade [`InputStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx).

O arquivo não exatamente tem um `path`. O arquivo normalmente está no corpo da requisição, através de uma sequência de bytes.

Comment: Valeu a resposta @Cigano, contudo, eu realmente preciso do path do arquivo... pelo meu model eu já consigo o acesso ao InputStream do arquivo e manipular o que preciso dele, mas para outra logica eu realmente preciso do local físico de onde o arquivo veio no momento do submit.

Comment: Você, o local da máquina do cliente?

Comment: no caso, o arquivo sempre vai vir de um servidor, contudo pode vir de pastas separadas.

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` não guarda informações do diretório de origem do arquivo. Acho que você vai ter que repensar sua lógica.