# Como contar colunas de um arquivo txt HttpPostedFileBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

No codigo abaixo, funcionaria perfeitamente se eu tivesse acesso ao `path` do arquivo upado no lado do cliente, contudo, não funciona assim. Então, eu gostaria de pedir a sugestão de vocês para uma outra forma de fazer isso.

Basicamente eu preciso de um contador de colunas, contudo meu arquivo está em memoria, visto que ele é um `HttpPostedFileBase`.

```
   string result = new StreamReader(model.Arquivo.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"caminhoQualquer\\arquivorandom.txt", Encoding.UTF7);             
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                var columns = lines[i].Split(';').Count();
                if(columns > 9)
                    throw new Exception("Não foi possível importar, pois o arquivo não tem a quantidade de colunas esperadas.");
            }
```

Agradeço todas as respostas.

Obs.: Sobre a questão do path, abri esse tópico ontem :
[Como obter o path de um arquivo(HttpPostedFileBase)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94701/como-obter-o-path-de-um-arquivohttppostedfilebase)

Mas não obtive sucesso.

Edit:

Como é a entrada:

Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo
Campo; campo; campo; campocampo ; campo

Ai no caso, o sistema teria que validar linha por linha a quantidade de colunas, se por acaso uma linha tenha mais colunas que a quantidade parametrizada, vai levantar o erro.

Comment: Neste teste que você fez, qual o comportamento esperado e qual o comportamento que realmente ocorreu?

Comment: O resultado foi exatamente o esperado, ele realizou o count das colunas separadas por ';' no arquivo. Validando linha a linha, Funciona perfeitamente. Mas, como disse antes, não conseguir recuperar o path do arquivo. O cenario ideal é a partir do arquivo que tenho dentro do model, eu consiga fazer o count das colunas. Claro que é exatamente o mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o result?

using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(model.Arquivo.InputStream)){
          var columns = stream.ReadLine().Split(';').Count();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado na resposta do @Renan

Eu cheguei nesta conclusão que sana meu problema :

```
public bool ValidarArquivo(ArquivoImportacaoModel model)
    {
        //List<string> conteudoArquivo = new List<string>();
        int colunas = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(model.Arquivo.InputStream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //conteudoArquivo.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                colunas = reader.ReadLine().Split(';').Count();

                if (colunas > 9)
                    throw new Exception("Não foi possível importar, pois o arquivo não tem a quantidade de colunas esperadas.");
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Desta forma resolveu.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa criar uma action no seu Controller para receber o arquivo:

```
        //Importando arquivos
        public ActionResult Importar()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

A sua View precisa de uma campo para upload do arquivo:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Importar", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Arquivo, new { type = "file" })
    <input type="submit" value="Importar">
}
```

Crie um método no seu Model para ler o conteúdo do seu arquivo:

```
    public class ImportacaoArquivo
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Arquivo é obrigatório.")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }

        internal String RetornarConteudoArquivo(Stream fileStream)
        {
            String conteudoArquivo;
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                conteudoArquivo = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return conteudoArquivo;
        }
    }
```

Você consegue obter o número de colunas no arquivo utilizando o método split(), exemplo:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Importar(ImportacaoArquivo importacaoArquivo) 
        {
            var conteudo = String.Empty;
            if(importacaoArquivo.Arquivo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                conteudo = importacaoArquivo.RetornarConteudoArquivo(importacaoArquivo.Arquivo.InputStream);
            }

            var totalColunas = conteudo.Split(';').Length;

            ViewData["conteudo"] = conteudo;
            ViewData["totalColunas"] = totalColunas;
            return Content("<b>Conteúdo: </b>" + conteudo + "<br><b>Total de Colunas: </b>" + totalColunas);
        }
```

O resultado seria algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acabei de efetuar o teste, mas para a minha entrada não funcionou.
Vou editar o post inicial com a entrada.

Comment: Cara, sua resposta não foi o que eu queria, mas me levou a resolver meu problema. Valeu.

Comment: Que bom que minha resposta foi útil e ajudou a resolver o problema :-)